# Sencha build failed for Extjs 6 for modern theme

Tags: extjs6-modern

I am using Extjs 6. When I am taking build from Sencha Cmd for modern theme it is showing an error like:

> Failed to resolve dependency Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error, because `Ext.state.*` does not exist in the modern theme.

If you also have a classic app, you should move the requires for `Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider` to the `MainView` / `MainViewController` of the classic app